# SwiftUI Dependency injection with environment object

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swiftui, architecture, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to create som kind of solution for injecting dependencies to SwiftUI view models and I have no idea whether I'm on to something or if I need to take this back to the drawing table.

```
struct MyAppName: App {

private static var serviceToInject = ServiceToInject()

@StateObject var viewModel1 = ViewModel1(service: serviceToInject)
@StateObject var viewModel2 = ViewModel2(service: serviceToInject)

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        if authenticationViewModel.isLoggedIn {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel1)
                .environmentObject(viewModel2)
        } else {
            LoginView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel2)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a possible to solution? I'm concerned about the use of static on the service. Is this maybee a better way to do it:

```
struct MyAppName: App {

@StateObject var viewModel1 = ViewModel1(service: ServiceToInject())
@StateObject var viewModel2 = ViewModel2(service: ServiceToInject())

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        if authenticationViewModel.isLoggedIn {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel1)
                .environmentObject(viewModel2)
        } else {
            LoginView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To have one shared instance or two separate ones is of course dependent on what the service does and how it is designed which we know nothing about. Perhaps off topic but it looks strange that a view needs two view models.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to inject an object to multiple instances.
You can make the ServiceToInject object an @EnvironmentObject, this way you can send it to multiple other classes: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-environmentobject-property-wrapper